# Doesn't recognise Timer.schedule

Tags: java, intellij-idea, timer, schedule

My Programm doesn't recognise schedule. I work with IntelliJ IDEA, and have version 2016.2.5 and JRE 1.8.0_112.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yIuyC.png)

```
package com.company.Game;

import java.util.*;

public class Timer
{


    public void run()
    {
        Timer m_Timer = new Timer();
        m_Timer.schedule(new TimerTask()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                //bla
            }
        },2000);
    }
}
```

Comment: schedule takes three arguments, not two. The last one is the period.

Comment: doesn't change anything, pls try yourself before commenting

Comment: And please refer to the linked question. Your own class is called `Timer`. That's the one being instantianted here.

Comment: I have not this problem with netbeans. Have you try to use other IDE?

Comment: @Aroniaina Did you name your class `public class Timer`?

Comment: Just change `java.Timer m_Timer = new Timer();` to `java.util.Timer m_Timer = new java.util.Timer();`